# Some time lamp server not loading files

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4

I have ubuntu18.04.1, php7.2, apache2.4 and two files: index.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="8000000" />
    <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and upload.php

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/procesu-valdymas/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';

echo $_FILES['userfile']['name']."\n";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Move OK.\n";
} else {
    echo "Move with error code:".$_FILES['userfile']['error'];
}

print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";
?>
```

I'm trying to upload the same file to server. Some times i can upload, but usually i can not. php_error.log and apache2 error.log does not show anything. On local server everything works perfectly.

When i can't upload browser just stack like in the photo. 
[image: Stack browser]. 
When browser stack access.log does not show anything, just after some time throw request timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

to the upload.php

Can you also paste output from

Likely your file exceeds some size limit, either max_upload_size or post_max_size in php.ini, or it takes longer than the maximum execution time, by default 30 seconds.

Comment: Now i have this setting in php.ini max_execution_time=300, max_input_time=600, error_reporting=E_All, display_error=on, post_max_size=8M, file_uploads=on, upload_max_filesize=8M. As i said php_error are clear

Comment: How big is your file? Bigger than 8M? It would not even be submitted then, see your HTML file